# Can't correctly write an int with printf

Tags: c, char, int

I have the code below:

```
char temp[1024];    
bzero(temp, 1024);    
for(i=0;i<4;i++){    
　　temp[i] = '9';    
}
int balance = atoi(temp);
```

When I print temp, it displays 9999. However, balance is assigned to nothing.
If I use:

```
printf("%c", balance);  // it prints nothing!
```

What's wrong with the code?

Comment: `atoi(temp)` returns 9999, this values is assigned to `balance`. What is wrong with that? I do not understand the question.

Comment: If you can get an int variable to be nothing, you've invented something new.

Comment: What do you mean by "balance is assigned to nothing"?

Comment: I means that if I use printf("%c", balance);, it prints nothing! So weird!

Comment: Well, `balance` is an `int`, `%c` is a character format, so what did you expect? Try `printf("%i", balance);` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format specifier with

```
printf("%c", balance);
```

which should be

```
printf("%d", balance);
```

because `balance` is defined as `int`.